# mySQL database structure to represent one user following another?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Basically I am trying to do a program with multiple users where each user posts his own pictures, and at the same time the user would be allowed to follow another user and see that user's articles.

I have the databases:

user(***user-id***)

pictures(**title**)

posted_by(**user-id**, **_title**)

and

followers(**user-id**, **follower-id_**)

Now, I am trying to write an SQL that retrieves both, the articles posted by the logged user, and the articles posted by the user's that the logged user follows.

The SQL I wrote is:

```
"SELECT * FROM pictures NATURAL JOIN users NATURAL JOIN posted_by NATURAL JOIN followers WHERE user-id = '" . $user-id . "' OR follower-id = '" . $user-id . "'";
```

Now, the problem with this is the part with

```
WHERE user-id = '" . $user-id
```

this part is not returning the right answer because user-id in the followers table does not actually represent this user's id, rather it represents the user-id of the person this user follows.

The question is: how can I restructure my followers table such that both follower-user-id and followee-user-id are represented by a different user in the user table, that way I can get the pictures I need in one query?

Comment: Use a UNION: one subquery returns the pictures posted by the user, the other subquery returns the pictures posted by his followees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your existing structure,

this query will give you your desired output.

```
select pst.userid, pic.title
    from pictures pic
      inner join posted_by pst on pic.title = pst.title
      left join followers flw on pst.userid = flw.userid
where pst.userid = <userid> or flw.followerid = <userid>
```

you can check the [fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/111b9/1)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way to design this would be to have a table named `post` as the parent table to tables `picture` and `article` (picture and article have foreign key to post). Putting common fields in post table (like user-id or date), you can use it to select and sort all the posts you want in a pretty simple SQL.